# return users who are not friends but attended the most events together

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a friends and events table like below

```
FriendsTable {
  user1_ID
  user2_ID
}

Events Table {
   event_ID
   user_ID
}
```

In my friends table, if user1 and user2 are friends, I'm only storing it in my db once where user1 < user2. So (1,2) will be found but (2,1) will not.

I'm trying to figure out a way to return users who are not friends but attended the same events in descending order. For example,

```
Events_Table{
  1, 1  //user1 attended event1
  1, 2  //user2 also attended event1
  3, 1 //user1 attended event 2
  3, 3 //user 3 attended event 3
  4, 1 //user1 attended event 4
  4, 3 //user3 attended event 4
  3, 5 // user 5 attended event 3
}

User_table{
  1, 2 //user1 is friends with user 2
}
```

So since user 1 and 3 are not friends but have attended event 3 and 4 together, and user 1 and 5 are not friends but attended event 3 
**the results would be (1,3) and (1,5)** in that order since user 1 and user 3 have more similar attended events.

**MY THINKING**

I don't want to make this post long but I was thinking of first using this to find friends that are not friends with another

```
select * from (select distinct f1.user1_id as user1, f2.user2_id as
user2 from FriendsTable as f1, FriendsTable as f2 where 
f1.user1_id < f2.user2_id MINUS select * from FriendsTable
```

and then somehow join it to the events table...

Comment: In mysql there isn't minus

Answer (score 0):

I would say first find all pair that attended in same event then subtract friends:

```
     select et1.event_ID, et1.user_id, et2.user_id 
       from Events_Table et1, Events_Table et2 
         where et1.event_ID=et2.event_ID and et1.user_ID < et2.user_id and 
           (et1.user_id, et2.user_id) not in (select user1_ID, user2_ID from FriendsTable)
        order by et1.event_ID, et1.user_id, et2.user_id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dinamic table based on a  self left join

```
select * from 
events where event_ID in ( 

     select distintc e.event_ID
     from events  as e 
     left join FriendsTable as f1 on f1.user1_id = e.user_ID
     left join FriendsTable as f2 on f2.user1_id = e.user_ID
     where f1.user_ID is null 
     or f2.user_ID is null 
 )
 order by events, user_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select q1.user_ID1, q1.user_ID2 from
    (select ET1.event_ID event_ID, ET1.user_ID user_ID1, et2.user_ID user_ID2 
        from EventsTable ET1 inner join EventsTable ET2 on ET1.event_ID = ET2.event_ID
        where ET1.user_ID < ET2.user_ID and (select count(*) from FriendsTable where user1_ID = et1.user_id and user2_ID = et2.user_id) = 0) q1
group by q1.user_ID1, q1.user_ID2
order by count(*) desc
```